# Extra dialog appearing on executing "Bulid with" command

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have made some change in my sublime text because of which I am getting this dialog on pressing Ctrl+Shift+B(Build with) instead of just directly running the code. Can someone tell me why this dialog is appearing and how it can be removed?

I am using sublime 3083 build on ubuntu 14.04.
[image]

Comment: Choose `C++ Single File - Run`. After you choose it the first time, I believe it will stop showing you the dialog box the next time you run the code.

Comment: On pressing ctrl+shift+b it shows me this dialog and on choosing "C++ Single File - Run" it sets it as default action. When next time i press Ctrl+B it just runs the code doesn't recompile and run it.

I want that sublime should recompile it when on pressing ctrl+b and should run the code directly on pressing ctrl+shift+b instead of showing that dialog.